# Cropped svg image

Tags: html, css

I have this minimal setup with an .svg image showing. The image is clipped a bit at the bottom. My arrow image is from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right?style=solid). Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .alpha {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      left: 0%;
      background: url('./arrow-right-solid.svg') 0 0 / 100% no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="alpha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: replaced the 100% with contain instead .. the icon not a square one like you may think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I set `/ 100%`, which made an image to stretch 100% in width. Because of that an image couldn't fit in height. It's not square image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .alpha {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      left: 0%;
      background: url('./arrow-right-solid.svg') 0 0 / contain no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="alpha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```